# How to find value in serialize fileds of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on `Rails application` where table have `serialize fields of colors`.

Save multiple values in `fields using serialize` and now want to search from that fields.

Suppose save in fields

```
Field Name - "colors"
First Row => '---\n- Yellow\n- Black\n- Pink\n'
Second Row => '---\n- Blue\n- Pink\n- Grey\n'
Third Row => '---\n- Pink\n- Grey\n'
```

Now i want to search "Grey" and "Blue" colors fields from table.

I tried below query

```
SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE (colors LIKE ('---\n- Grey\n- Blue\n'))
```

And in `Rails`

```
@clrs = Profile.where('colors LIKE (?)', params[:user][:colors].to_yaml )
```

But not found result proper results. Its match only perfect value.

What i have to do so found both color columns?

Thanks

Comment: You will most likely not get great performance no matter how you search on that data. To make searches efficient, you have to help the database figure out what's important, not search on random substrings. Full text search _may_ help here since it extracts the essence of the fields (the text) and indexes that, so it may be worth a shot.

Comment: Please `do not` abuse `code formatting`. Use it only for `code`. Otherwise, your `eyes` will `hurt`.

Answer (score 0):

i think it must be

```
SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE (colors LIKE ('%---\n- Grey\n- Blue\n%'))
```

So, in rail.

```
params[:user][:colors].to_yaml
```

must inclued '%' in head and tail string